# Xilinx FPGA decoupling cap layout (traces and vias)

Tags: pcb-design, fpga, xilinx, layout, decoupling-capacitor

I have the decoupling capacitors located close to sparatan 7 (<2000 mil). I'm trying to route these and connect it to the BGA pin. According to xilinx UG393, I shouldn't use same vias.

> PCB layout engineers often try to squeeze more parts into a small area
> by sharing vias among multiple capacitors. This technique should not
> be used under any circumstances. PDS improvement is very small when a
> second capacitor is connected to an existing capacitor’s vias. The
> capacitor mounting (lands, traces, and vias) typically contributes
> about the same amount or more inductance than the capacitor's own
> parasitic self-inductance.

I'm trying to connect them using single trace and then add a via to touch the 3.3 V power plane. I don't think this will induce any additional parasitic capacitance. I'm placing a via perpendicular with short trace. Is this correct ? Or do I need to add separate vias [image]to each cap.

Comment: "*additional parasitic capacitance*" You mean parasitic inductance? A via is just another kind of trace. If you shouldn't share vias then you shouldn't share traces. More traces = more parallel inductances = less inductance.

Comment: Thanks,  you said "More traces = more parallel inductances = less inductance." What you mean by that ? If have more traces then more inductance. So if I share traces then there are less of them. Is that what you want ?

Comment: Do you not know how inductors behave in parallel? If not, then you need to read up on how equivalent resistances, inductances, and capacitances when in series and parallel.

Comment: Got it ! that was such a simple principle which I knew but, didn't get to surface till you brought it up. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

[image]Here is the answer.
(connecting Cap to Planes)The wider the trace, the lower the inductance. The same goes for connecting component pads to planes. For each additional via (multiple vias in a pad), inductance will be reduced. The capacitance between the power and ground planes can also be very useful for decoupling when placed physically close together.

(connecting Component lead to cap) : Regardless of whether the PCB is simple or complex, almost all products require a trace to be present between a component lead and capacitor, or interconnect via. This interconnect trace, also identified as pin-escape, breakout, and similar terminology. A trace must be routed from the component to a via located nearby for connection to a signal, power, or ground plane. It is not possible, manufacturing wise, to have large vias embedded in a component's mounting pad. Solder may flow into the via, preventing the component from having a secure bond connection in addition to other manufacturing concerns

I got this from chapter 3 of Printed Circuit Board Design Techniques for EMC Compliance, Second Edition